# simulate route in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I have this route defined

```
Route::get('test/something/{id?}', 'MyController@mymethod')->name('test.something');
```

So if go to `domain_1.com/test/something/123` I get some page with data.

Now, I want to to show the exact same thing if the site if accessed form another domain with subdomain. I've defined this:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'subdomain.domain_2.com'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'MyController@mymethod', ['id' => 123]);
});
```

but I got to `subdomain.domain_2.com`, I get *Too few arguments* error. How can I pass the `id` parameter to the method in the route?

Comment: do you mean that the id gonna be static as "123" in the subdomain ?

Comment: @RatebHabbab yes, that subdomain is going to use 123. someday another subdomain will point to 456 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `redirect` like:

```
Route::get('test/something/{id?}', 'MyController@mymethod')->name('test.something');

Route::group(['domain' => 'subdomain.domain_2.com'], function() {
    
    Route::get('/', function(){
        return redirect('/test/something/123');
    });

});
```

If you don't want to use `redirect`, you could check the current url from the method in the controller like:

```
public function mymethod($id=null){
    $currentUrl = request()->url();

    if (strpos($currentUrl, 'subdomain') !== false) {
        $id = 123;
    }

    // your function
}
```

Comment: but that redirects me to subdomain.domain_2.com/test/something/123....I just want to go to the subdomain without seeing the whole url with parameters

Comment: check the edits

Answer (score 0):

I've found this piece of code that gets the job done, but I'm not sure is the correct way to achieve what I want

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'subdomain.domain_2.com'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', [ 'as' => 'some_alias', function()
    {
        return app()->make(App\Http\Controllers\MyController::class)->callAction('mymethod', $parameters = [ 'id' => 123 ]);
    }]);    
});
```